# Topics for a UX talk to statisticians

Tags: education

I have been asked to give a 1-hour talk to a meetup group of statisticians and data scientists. I haven't been given any guidelines - just that they'd like something interesting and entertaining.

I have been in UX for 20 years, and could probably talk at the required level about all the subspecialties (research, testing, interaction design, visual design, etc.) and processes (UCD, etc.). I've given many talks in my career (seminars, job talks) but nothing with this broad a mandate to an audience from a different field.

My question is - if you have given a talk anything like this, what have you found to work best?

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: If you're looking to speak on something that relates to their field as well, perhaps data visualization (how user experience and large data collections overlap), A/B testing (how collecting data impacts real world products), etc.

Comment: Ideas... I would think something like the long term trends, differences and similarities observed between users now and from n years ago, behaviors specific to age cohorts. Also the difference between what we can learn from studies vs. the insights from small usability tests... And you could snoop https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and look at popular tags there for ideas of what might interest statisticians.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. These are helpful. I'll probably break the talk down into several smaller sections, so as not to get stuck on a particular topic which happens not to interest this particular audience.